# How to get all the text that can be visible in html code using any gem in ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I need to get all the text which will be visible to user if the given html page is shown in browser using any ruby gem. Now I am using Mechanize and Nokogiri to scrap the data from website but I need the words or text that are visible to user. Please state any gem or method which I can use to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with Nokogiri.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

source = "<div>Manu <span> hi</span></div>"

Nokogiri::HTML(source).text
# => Manu  hi
```

It'll still have some issue with newline and spacings. You'll just have to handle those issues yourself.